# resigned ipa installs in iOS 8 but not installing in iOS 9+

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, jenkins, codesign

I am resigning the app with another developer account using the following script

```
codesign -f -s "Distribution Certificate Name" <app-name>.app
```

The app installs but not opens.
This is the approach everybody is following

But it is not working for me

Please find the device log below and let me know if you need more information

**Device Log**

```
Jul 18 20:24:31 iPad atc[31] <Warning>: |error| Unable to create file lock.
Jul 18 20:24:31 iPad crash_mover[235] <Notice>: (Error) NPSLogging: <NPSDomainAccessor.m +[NPSDomainAccessor resolveActivePairedDevicePairingID:pairingDataStore:]:41> Failed to resolve pairing ID ((null)) or data store ((null)) for active device
Jul 18 20:24:31 iPad profiled[125] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Provisioning profiles changed
Jul 18 20:24:31 iPad profiled[125] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Provisioning profiles changed
Jul 18 20:24:31 iPad profiled[125] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Provisioning profiles changed
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad storebookkeeperd[93] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDDomainSyncedStorageController]  target sync date from client: 2016-06-28 14:54:42 +0000 (in 10.00 sec)
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad storebookkeeperd[93] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDDomainSyncedStorageController]  setting target date to: 2016-06-28 14:54:42 +0000 (in 62625085527.50 sec)
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad storebookkeeperd[93] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDDomainSyncedStorageController]  scheduling sync (via BackgroundTaskJob) 9.999761 seconds from now...
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad atc[31] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing placeholder for com.test.app
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad UserEventAgent[17] <Error>: Could not get event name for stream/token: com.apple.backgroundtaskagent/99: 132: Request for stale data
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad installd[40] <Notice>: 0x101dac000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/tmp/com.apple.atc.Apps/com.test.app.app" type Placeholder requested by atc (pid 31)
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad installd[40] <Notice>: 0x101dac000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.test.app; Version=0.0.7, ShortVersion=(null)>
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad MobileStorageMounter[237] <Error>: 0x199a51310 Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such process
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad MobileStorageMounter[237] <Error>: 0x199a51310 Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad MobileStorageMounter[237] <Error>: 0x199a51310 Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad MobileStorageMounter[237] <Error>: 0x199a51310 Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad MobileStorageMounter[237] <Error>: 0x199a51310 Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad MobileStorageMounter[237] <Error>: 0x199a51310 Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad MobileStorageMounter[237] <Error>: 0x199a51310 Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad installd[40] <Notice>: 0x101dac000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:withError:]: Made container live for com.test.app at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CF25F5C1-3292-489E-827B-704042967A94
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad installd[40] <Notice>: 0x101dac000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:withError:]: Made container live for com.test.app at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C5A68C95-B468-4CD6-B63C-AE78788A3C84
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad installd[40] <Notice>: 0x101dac000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Staging: 0.01s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.16s; Overall: 0.18s
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad deleted[148] <Warning>: LaunchServices: no bundle found with identifier com.apple.CacheDelete
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad atc[31] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x15766e400> com.test.app (Placeholder) withPhase:3
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad atc[31] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.test.app.InstallingPlaceholder - <NSProgress: 0x1576a27c0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad atc[31] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x159114b20> com.test.app (Placeholder) withPhase:0
Jul 18 20:24:32 iPad lsd[77] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: 0x13ed12ee0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   to 0
Jul 18 20:24:34 iPad atc[31] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.test.app.Loading - <NSProgress: 0x1575d8370> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9900 / Completed: 990 of 1000   called, removing progress from cache
Jul 18 20:24:34 iPad SpringBoard[50] <Warning>: Killing com.test.app for app installation
Jul 18 20:24:34 iPad atc[31] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder <LSApplicationProxy: 0x15766e400> com.test.app (Placeholder)
Jul 18 20:24:34 iPad atc[31] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x15766e400> com.test.app (Placeholder) withPhase:1
Jul 18 20:24:34 iPad lsd[77] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: 0x13ed12ee0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5900 / Completed: 59 of 100   to 1
Jul 18 20:24:34 iPad installd[40] <Notice>: 0x100584000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/test.ipa" type Customer requested by atc (pid 31)
Jul 18 20:24:34 iPad installd[40] <Notice>: 0x100584000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.test.app; Version=0.0.7, ShortVersion=0.0.7>
Jul 18 20:24:35 iPad profiled[125] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Provisioning profiles changed
Jul 18 20:24:35 iPad installd[40] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Jul 18 20:24:35 iPad mobile_assertion_agent[157] <Notice>: service_one_connection: Connection closed for client iTunes.
Jul 18 20:24:35 iPad mobile_assertion_agent[157] <Notice>: service_one_connection: Connection closed for client iTunes.
Jul 18 20:24:35 iPad installd[40] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Jul 18 20:24:35 iPad installd[40] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Jul 18 20:24:35 iPad installd[40] <Error>: 0x100584000 -[MIInstallableBundle performVerificationWithError:]: 521: Application is missing the application-identifier entitlement.
Jul 18 20:24:35 iPad installd[40] <Error>: 0x100584000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Verification stage failed
Jul 18 20:24:35 iPad atc[31] <Error>: 0x102294000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke240: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=63 "Application is missing the application-identifier entitlement." UserInfo=0x1575f4d40 {LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, FunctionName=-[MIInstallableBundle performVerificationWithError:], SourceFileLine=521, NSLocalizedDescription=Application is missing the application-identifier entitlement.}
Jul 18 20:24:35 iPad atc[31] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
Jul 18 20:24:35 iPad lsd[77] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app com.test.app
Jul 18 20:24:35 iPad atc[31] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.test.app.Installing - <NSProgress: 0x1577ee5f0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
Jul 18 20:24:36 iPad librariand[163] <Error>: ubiquity account is not configured (or is disabled for this client), not creating collection
Jul 18 20:24:36 iPad librariand[163] <Error>: error in _handle_client_request: LibrarianErrorDomain/10/Unable to configure the collection.
Jul 18 20:24:36 iPad bird[131] <Error>: unable to determine evictable space: Error Domain=LibrarianErrorDomain Code=10 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LibrarianErrorDomain error 10 - Unable to configure the collection.)" UserInfo=0x15761d5f0 {NSDescription=Unable to configure the collection.}
Jul 18 20:24:42 iPad storebookkeeperd[93] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDDomainSyncedStorageController]  running synchronizeImmediatelyWithCompletionHandler: now
Jul 18 20:24:42 iPad storebookkeeperd[93] <Warning>: [StoreBookkeeper] -[SBKUniversalPlaybackPositionStore _onQueueRunTaskWithName:taskCompletionHandler:runTaskBlock:] _onQueueSync - beginning synchronize operation...
Jul 18 20:24:42 iPad storebookkeeperd[93] <Warning>: [StoreBookkeeper] -[SBKUniversalPlaybackPositionStore _onQueueLoadBagContextWithCompletionHandler:] _onQueueLoadBag - load bag operation beginning...
Jul 18 20:24:42 iPad storebookkeeperd[93] <Warning>: [StoreBookkeeper] __81-[SBKUniversalPlaybackPositionStore _onQueueLoadBagContextWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke411 _onQueueLoadBag - load bag completed.
Jul 18 20:24:42 iPad storebookkeeperd[93] <Warning>: [StoreBookkeeper] __89-[SBKUniversalPlaybackPositionStore _onQueueSynchronizeImmediatelyWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke _onQueueSync - synchronize operation beginning...
Jul 18 20:24:44 iPad storebookkeeperd[93] <Warning>: [StoreBookkeeper] [SBKTransactionController.m:447] Transaction Failed: <SBKSyncTransaction: 0x147d6ab40> domain = com.apple.upp, SYNC: anchor=0 -- Error: <SBKStoreError:0x147d94940> "Error Code = SBKStoreErrorCodeStoreAccountSessionExpired (-1004)"
Jul 18 20:24:44 iPad storebookkeeperd[93] <Warning>: [StoreBookkeeper] __96-[SBKUniversalPlaybackPositionStore _onQueueRunTaskWithName:taskCompletionHandler:runTaskBlock:]_block_invoke279 _onQueueSync - synchronize completed.  ERROR = 'Error Code = SBKStoreErrorCodeStoreAccountSessionExpired (-1004)'.
Jul 18 20:24:44 iPad storebookkeeperd[93] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDJobScheduler]  Could not synchronize domain 'com.apple.upp' (<SBKStoreError:0x147e14a10> "Error Code = SBKStoreErrorCodeStoreAccountSessionExpired (-1004)").  Synchronization will be re-attempted when the network connectivity, or account status has changed.
Jul 18 20:24:50 iPad locationd[57] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
```

Comment: This command used to work for me too.Can you get the device logs at the time of installing ? (Make the selection like *Window -> Devices* choose your device in the sidebar and capture the device console logs

Comment: Hello Durai, I was edited code please check it and respond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from *iOS 8.3 entitlement for the app is mandatory*.

```
codesign -f -s "Distribution Certificate Name" <app-name>.app
```

When you resign the app using above command *it removes the existing entitlement*

So the command that you are using works before iOS 8.4.1

So in order for the app to run from iOS 8.4.1 you have to sign the app along with entitlements*

Here is the command that creates entitlements file

```
codesign -d --entitlements - <appname>.app > entitlements.plist
```

then sign the app with entitlements

```
codesign -f -s "Distribution Certificate Name" '--entitlements' 'entitlements.plist' <app-name>.app
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer